# Keyboard with CTRL left of A

Tags: keyboard

Are there any "reasonably priced" :-) keyboards with the Ctrl key to the left of the A key? I know I can remap keys, both in Emacs and in the host OS, but I'm looking for something in hardware. That way, I get the Ctrl key where I want it, even if I plug the keyboard into an arbitrary computer where I may have only limited control over the operating environment. The only ones I am aware of are the Happy Hacking Keyboards, but the cheapest one seems to be over $200. If I used it a lot, it would be worth it, but not right now...

Comment: I'm voting for re-opening this, or having it migrated to somewhere like https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboards with a pointer.  It the sort of question that Emacs users may be far more prone to ask than other computer users, so I think it's a reasonable thing to address in some fashion at Emacs.SE.

Comment: @phils: Dunno about the general question of asking about hardware to use with Emacs. You might have a point there. But this question seems to encourage opinion-based answers, since it asks about "reasonably priced" (undefined). If it were edited to ask for a keyboard cheaper than $200 then it would be more straightforward. But even with that kind of question I fear we'd get into merchant links (~ads) and even possibly spam. I think that's the kind of thing that might be better on an opinion & discussion site such as Reddit. I'm going to decline to vote on whether or not it should be reopened.